# why set FrameLayout up setOnClickListener is not working in databinding

Tags: android, data-binding

I got a requirement to set up a FrameLayout SetOnClickListener in a Toolbar. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuUrC.png). I set that in Fragment's `onCreateView` under the used databinding situation , it isn't working.

Do I forget part of something? Which part is missing.

My ToolBar XML: `folder_path_navigation_bar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_height">

  <HorizontalScrollView
   android:id="@+id/folderPath_horizontalScrollView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_height"
   android:fadeScrollbars="false"
   android:fillViewport="true"
   android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/folder_path_scrollbar_thumb"
   android:splitMotionEvents="false"
   android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chat_search">

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/folderPath_folder_path"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_height"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/blue_B500"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false" >


     </LinearLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/workspace_search"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/actionbar_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_height"
        android:background="@color/blue_B500">

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/divider_line" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnsearch"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Common_003"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search" />

    </FrameLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

My `Fragment.java` code:

```
public class WorkspaceFragment extends AppBaseFragment implements
    SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener,
    ActionMode.Callback {

public static final String TAG = "WorkspaceFragment";

private FragmentWorkspaceBinding binding;

private FolderPathNavigationBarBinding workspacebarbinding;//---------------binding set here


private WorkspaceAdapter workspaceAdapter;
private WorkspaceDialogHelper workspaceDialogHelper;
protected MainActivity mainActivity;

protected WorkspaceFolderExplorer workspaceFolderExplorer;
protected String actionControlType = WorkspaceControlType.CHANGE_ROOT_PATH;
private ActionMode actionMode;
private HandleActionBarEvent actionModeTitleBar;
private WorkspaceHelper workspaceHelper;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
private MenuItem actionMenu;
private ActionModeMenuEvent actionModeMenuEvent;
private ConflictDialog conflictDialog;
private WorkspaceActionModeToolbar workspaceActionModeToolbar;
private Menu menu;

@Override
protected boolean isEnabledWhiteToolBar() {
    return true;
}

@Override
protected int getLayoutId() {
    return R.layout.fragment_workspace;
}

@Override
protected boolean isEnabledToolBar() {
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isEnabledDataBinding() {
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isEnabledFab() {
    return false;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    binding = getViewDataBinding();
    initToolbar();//<---------------------------------------------set up here in onCreateView
    workspaceDialogHelper = new WorkspaceDialogHelper(getContext());
    workspaceAdapter = new WorkspaceAdapter(getContext());
    binding.recyclerView.setEmptyView(binding.recyclerEmptyView);
    binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(workspaceAdapter);

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            if (workspaceAdapter.getItemViewType(position)
                    != workspaceAdapter.getGridModeViewType(position)) {
                return gridLayoutManager.getSpanCount();
            }
            return 1;
        }
    });
    updateLayoutManager();

    binding.swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    binding.titleBar.getRoot().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    workspaceActionModeToolbar = new WorkspaceActionModeToolbar(getContext(), binding.titleActionMode);
    workspaceActionModeToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    getWorkspaceFolderExplorer();
    workspaceHelper = new WorkspaceHelper();
    actionModeMenuEvent = new ActionModeMenuEvent(getContext());
    return binding.getRoot();
}

private void initToolbar() {
    workspacebarbinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()),R.layout.folder_path_navigation_bar,null,false);
    workspacebarbinding.workspaceSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("click","should do something here, but no execute here..");
        }
    });
}
                               .
                               .
                               .
                               .
                               .
                               .
                          other function
```